# Select html an object <a> with href and child <li>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Looking for option in js/css to select (n) `<li>` in my code, but i need to have indicate that `<li>` have parent with current `<a>` with specyfic indicated href link.

```html
<a href="www.link.com">CATEGORY NAME</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                        <div class="123">
    <div class="categories ">
      <span>Categories:</span>

      <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://someweb.com/"> 1 </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://someweb.com/"> 2 this is what i need to select </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Many thanks for respound!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
li a[href='https://someweb.com/']:eq(1)
```

```js
$("li a[href='https://someweb.com/']:eq(1)").css("background","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <li>
  <a href="https://someweb.com/"> 1 </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="https://someweb.com/"> 2 this is what i need to select </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="https://someweb.com/"> 3 </a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select that specific URL?

```css
a[href='https://specificWeb.com/']{
 background: red;
 }
```

```html
<a href="www.link.com">CATEGORY NAME</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                        <div class="123">
    <div class="categories ">
      <span>Categories:</span>
      <ul>
      <li>
      <a href="https://someweb.com/"> 1 </a>
      </li>

      <li>
      <a href="https://specificWeb.com/"> 2 this is what i need to select </a>
      </li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But i think a better solution will be by using classes:

```css
.my-target-url {
 background: red;
 
 }
```

```html
<a href="www.link.com">CATEGORY NAME</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                        <div class="123">
    <div class="categories ">
      <span>Categories:</span>
      <ul>
      <li>
      <a href="https://someweb.com/"> 1 </a>
      </li>

      <li>
      <a class="my-target-url"href="https://specificWeb.com/"> 2 this is what i need to select </a>
      </li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And if urls are not hardcoded, add a logic that toggles the class